# Modern Hebrew: Where can I find a chart of all the verb conjugation rules in a single place?

Tags: hebrew

I have had three textbooks so far (Al Yesod, Brandeis, and one in an ulpan) and they all spread the verb rules across multiple chapters.

Hebrew is amazing in how systematized it is. (Of course there are exceptions, that isn't what this is about....) But I am struggling to find the finite (1-3 page) set of tables that says: Plug your shoresh into this table and turn the crank.

Where to find?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The closest free online resource that I know of is [this](https://www.pealim.com/dict/?r1=%D7%91&r2=%D7%9B&&rf=%D7%A8&num-radicals=3) at *pealim.com*. You can set the shoresh and the binyan. Pretty good.

A good book, if you can get it, is [Hebrew Verbs and Conjugations](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B002KLPAJS) by Shraga Assif. It shows pretty much every construction possible for lots of roots. I bought my copy in Israel several years back.

[Teach Me Hebrew](https://www.teachmehebrew.com/) Lessons 14-22 have a nice, free overview of roots and binyan. And somewhat related to this is another resource, [Chapters 12-20](https://www.l2press.com/hebrew-grammar-by-example-sample) of [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1952161029) (Hebrew Grammar By Example: Dual Language Hebrew-English, Interlinear & Parallel Text, L2 Press publisher) give a good overview of the roots and binyan.

Comment: Thanks!  Where is the summary of the system ... really a hassle that it is so spread out. I know about pealim.com. It is a great reference, but is not a document on the system...  I will check out the resources you mention.

Comment: The link to "this book" is bad. Can you name the book (title and author) for posterity?

Answer (score 2):

I've found Lewis Glinert's [Modern Hebrew: An Essential Grammar](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06XDQJZYH) (no relationship) to be a great resource. The verb charts are not all in one page, but the are *concise* and easy to look up.

This is *not* an introductory Hebrew book - the author even mentions this in his introduction:

> *Modern Hebrew* is *not* a graded, step-by-step coursebook. Of those there are many. It supplies what they generally lack: a simple, up-to-date outline of Hebrew structure.

To use this book, you need a basic understanding of the structure of Hebrew and its writing system. The book presumes you are proficient in the alphabet and vowel marks, providing *no* help in reading. If you can't quite read yet, leave this book on the shelf and learn to read or recite a Hebrew text with full vowelling.

The first section of the book covers regular structures, including *all* the regular *binyanim* with charts showing how to plug in your *shoresh* to get any tense.

The second section illustrates the most common patterns of irregularity, such as how roots with "gutturals" (e.g. terminal ה, etc.) affect the pattern. I've found that most Hebrew coursebooks are particularly weak in that regard - they treat these forms as purely irregular and something to memorize verb-by-verb. This book explains how that is not necessary.